# Low-rank matrix completion is NP-hard

Tags: optimization, reductions, np-hard, matrices, sparse-matrices

In looking into the problem of low-rank matrix completion / relaxations of the general problem to derive exact solutions, many papers cite that the original formulation is NP-hard but I cannot find a proof of this fact. The problem is as follows.

Given a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ of rank $r$ (again, assumed to be low) and we only have a partial observation of the matrix entries, say $\Omega \subseteq [n] \times [m]$ we want to find an $X$ that solves

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset{X}{\text{minimize}} & \mbox{rank}(X)\\ \text{subject to} & X_{ij} = M_{ij}, \quad \forall ij \in \Omega \end{array} $$

In particular, the following papers mention this result in the abstract or introduction without further elaboration (see [R2009](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0651) and [HMRW2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.2331)). Is there a well-known proof of this fact or easy reduction to understand the result?

Comment: You may want to take a look at Parrilo's [The convex algebraic geometry of rank minimization](https://web.mit.edu/parrilo/www/pubs/talkfiles/ISMP2009.pdf) (2009) [PDF].

Comment: If no one answers here within a month, consider reposting at [Theoretical CS](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com).  Crosslink the questions.

Comment: You can improve the question by providing full references.  Someone googling those papers might find this question and be tempted to answer.  By hiding the authors and the titles, you are not helping yourself.